# Meaning of sentence with 2 conditionals

Tags: conditional-constructions

I said out loud, "I will ride my boat....not if it is raining....if the wind speed is 5mph”

Does this mean:
I will ride my boat if it is not raining outside and if the wind speed is 5mph. That is, the 2 conditionals “not if it is raining” and “if the wind speed is 5mph” are equal to each other.

Or is the 2nd conditional serving as a conditional to the first conditional: If the wind speed is 5mph, then I will not ride my boat if it is raining outside?

Comment: I think you may need to give the entire quotation to determine the meaning.

Comment: Your sentence isn't very clear.  In particular "I will ride my boat not if it is raining" is not grammatically correct.

Comment: This is basically the same question as the other one which you asked.  I've suggested that the other one be closed duplicate of this, since at least this one has some comprehensible meaning.

Comment: This is a question about formal logic. It is not about the English language. In order for it to be about English, you need to form the isolated phrases into a coherent sentence using the rules of grammar. If, on the other hand, you wish to ask about formal logic then you must use the correct notation. You use the string "...." as a separator. That symbol is not defined in logic, so you must give us its definition before we can answer.   At the moment this question is insufficiently specified so I will vote to close it until clarification is given.